# Can't figure out how to set Path for Cron job

Tags: python, django, cron

I have been going through all the different cases and examples online but I really don't understand how to set the Path for my cron job.

When I try to add the job I get this error:

/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/crontab: not found
adding cronjob: (671a82cf1733e868bud228e0587aec4d) -> ('1 0-23/3 * 3-10 1-7', 'management.cron.mlb_games_today')
sh: 1: /usr/bin/crontab: not found

I see this question has been asked a million times but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```py
    Settings.py
    CRONJOBS = [
    ('1 0-23/3 * 3-10 1-7', 'management.cron.mlb_games_today')
    ]
```

Comment: can you show us your dir path where this script resides? and also how did you run the cronjob?

Comment: The function is in a cron.py file in my management app. I get the error when I 'python manage.py crontab add'

Comment: django is not detecting crontab here. So if its on your local or any server , check if cron is installed properly

Comment: I am followed the steps on https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/ and it said it was successfully installed when I did 'pip install django-crontab'

Comment: Did you install it on the same environment on which django is running?

Comment: Yes. On my GitPod workspace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231050/discussion-between-neeraj-and-ryan-thomas).